# Determining which raw IR code to use for AC

Tags: esp8266, ir

I'm new on this so go easy on me.

I'm trying to make an IR blaster to control my TV and ACs. I realized that when I capture the IR code, power button/temp up and down/mode send raw codes that are almost similar to each other.

I've searched the net(maybe missed some answers) and came through [this](https://myesp8266.blogspot.com/2016/05/keep-your-house-cool-with-esp8266.html). The raw IR code provided on the blog did turned on my AC but I wasn't able to turn it off. So I think that the code isn't the power button. That's because I remember leaving the AC off at 23°C and when I send that code, my AC started at 20°C.

So, how do I know which code to use for off, temp up etc? The codes I captured seems not to work when I send the codes to the AC. Nothing happened. No beep or anything. I'm using a GREE AC by the way.

Here's an example of the raw code that turned on my AC:

```
uint16_t irACon1[139] = {9050, 4500, 800, 1600, 750, 550, 700, 550, 700, 1600, 750, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 1600, 750, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 1600, 750, 1600, 750, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 1600, 750, 550, 700, 1600, 750, 550, 700, 550, 700, 1600, 750, 550, 700, 19950, 750, 500, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 1600, 750, 550, 700, 550, 750, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 550, 700, 1550, 800, 550, 750, 500, 700, 1600, 750};
```

And few other codes that I had captured:

```
Raw: (139) 9068, -4404, 708, -1580, 712, -488, 712, -484, 712, -1580, 712, -1580, 708, -1580, 712, -488, 708, -488, 708, -1584, 708, -1584, 708, -1580, 708, -492, 708, -488, 704, -496, 704, -492, 708, -492, 708, -492, 704, -492, 708, -492, 708, -488, 712, -488, 712, -1580, 708, -1580, 712, -488, 712, -484, 712, -488, 712, -488, 712, -484, 712, -1580, 712, -484, 712, -1580, 712, -484, 716, -484, 712, -1580, 712, -484, 712, -19848, 684, -512, 704, -496, 708, -492, 708, -488, 708, -492, 708, -488, 712, -488, 712, -488, 708, -488, 712, -488, 712, -484, 712, -488, 712, -488, 708, -1580, 712, -488, 712, -484, 712, -488, 708, -488, 712, -488, 712, -488, 708, -488, 712, -488, 708, -488, 712, -488, 712, -488, 708, -488, 712, -488, 708, -492, 708, -488, 708, -492, 708, -1584, 704, -1584, 708, 

Raw: (139) 8988, -4540, 556, -1736, 564, -688, 520, -676, 524, -652, 548, -1688, 600, -1688, 604, -648, 548, -652, 548, -1688, 604, -1684, 604, -1688, 604, -648, 548, -652, 548, -648, 548, -652, 548, -652, 548, -648, 548, -652, 548, -652, 548, -648, 548, -676, 524, -1688, 600, -1688, 604, -676, 520, -676, 524, -676, 524, -672, 524, -676, 524, -1712, 576, -680, 520, -1688, 604, -756, 440, -788, 412, -1688, 600, -816, 384, -20092, 468, -840, 348, -848, 352, -848, 352, -820, 384, -812, 388, -788, 412, -784, 412, -784, 416, -760, 440, -760, 436, -760, 440, -756, 444, -756, 440, -1824, 468, -780, 416, -760, 440, -756, 444, -728, 468, -732, 468, -728, 472, -700, 496, -704, 496, -700, 496, -676, 524, -676, 520, -652, 548, -648, 552, -624, 572, -624, 576, -620, 580, -1740, 548, -620, 580,
```

PS: Sorry for my bad English. And I somehow feel that the title isn't specific so let me know if there's a better title I should put.

**UDPATE**: Now the off and temp up is working but the temp is somewhat like an on button. It instantly put my AC on 23°C and won't increase when pressed multiple time. I understand that AC's remote fires the whole setup string when a button is pressed so which means different temps has different codes?

Answer (score 1):

It appears from the data you've posted, the remote is holding the presets for what the A/C unit needs to be doing when after every button is pressed.  This will keep the remote with LCD disply? in Sync with the A/C master.

Ie.  The remote is sending an entire setup string EVERY time ANY button is pressed.

Can you post a capture of an ON and OFF Raw's only?  Do not press any other buttons after pressing ON, or before pressing OFF.

Comment: I see. But surely there's a way to know which raw code control what, isn't it? And here's the on and off raw code: https://pastebin.com/sKVWecLh

Comment: You are on the right track, but I think you need an expert for a better answer.